# Using GoalSeek Functionality in an Excel VBA Module

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone help me understand why the first sub works but the second gives an invalid reference?

```
Sub tester1()

    Range("Q5").GoalSeek goal:=2000000, changingcell:=Range("P5")

End Sub


Sub tester3()
    Dim rngRow As Range
    For Each rngRow In Range("P5").Rows
        rngRow.Cells(0, 1).GoalSeek goal:=2000000, changingcell:=rngRow.Cells(0, 0)
    Next rngRow
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cells(0, 1)` and `Cells(0, 0)` are invalid - rows and columns should be greater than 0

```
Range("A1") = Cells(1, 1)    'Cells(row, col)
Range("A2") = Cells(2, 1)
Range("B1") = Cells(1, 2)
Range("B2") = Cells(2, 2)
```

---

Test with this:

```
Sub tester3()

    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Range("Q5:Q10")

        cel.GoalSeek Goal:=2000000, ChangingCell:=cel.Offset(0, -1)

    Next rngRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Offset can be confusing: `Range("B2").Offset(-1, -1)` is `Range("A1")`

Comment: thanks.  using the correct cell reference still returns Invalid Reference:  rngRow.Cells(5, 17).GoalSeek goal:=2000000, changingcell:=rngRow.Cells(5, 16).  Cell(5,17) is a formula and Cell(5,16) is a value.

Comment: `cel.GoalSeek Goal:=2000000, ChangingCell:=cel.Offset(0, 1)` - does this work?

Comment: I still get Invalid Reference.  The formula in Q5 is a UDF.  It works fine if I change values in P5 manually to find the solution, but not with VBA.  FYI i'm trying to get this to work in one cell so I can set it off to calculate for 500 cells below

Comment: Are Calculations set to Manual or Automatic? (Tab Formulas -> Calculation Options)

Comment: it is set to automatic

Comment: Update the For to this: `For Each cel In Range("Q5:Q10")` (see my edit)

Comment: Yes that works.  Thank you very much.  What is it that was causing the problem?  Note the Offset should be (0,-1)

Comment: I updated the Offset to -1. I think you were not using the proper references: `Range("A2").Cells(1, 2).Select` will select cell B2 - A2 is the anchor for the next reference